# Can I use an isolated error amplifier to monitor isolated battery voltage?

Tags: operational-amplifier, isolation

I have a scenario where I'm using an isolated switching regulator to regulate a battery voltage (9-18V) for my system (12V.) I need to keep track of the battery voltage, but due to the isolation I'm obviously not going to be able to use a normal op-amp or resitive divider to do so or I'll negate any isolation I have.

I was thinking about using an isolation amplifier to achieve my goals here and just wanted to sense check what I'm doing (circuit below.)

Based on [the datasheet](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/TLP7920_datasheet_en_20160523.pdf?did=30395&prodName=TLP7920) it looks like the part is linear between -200 and 200mV so I've added a divider to reach near enough this range. Since I only have a unipolar input I've tied the negative input and output to their respective grounds. With the stated gain of 8.2 I expect at 200mV input I should see 1.64V on the output.

Is this a good one-chip approach to solving my problem of isolated battery measurement? Will it work as I expect it to?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Will it work as I expect it to?

Yes, but with a few modifications.

The IC output is differential, so grounding one of them may not be a good idea. It's better to use a diff-to-single-ended converter (basically a single-supply differential amplifier):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4hepB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: If the Vin- is grounded, then why would it be a bad idea to ground Vout-? Would this not be expected to be static? If not, could I not just leave Vout- floating?

Comment: @Sensors Grounding Vin– doesn't allow you to ground Vout–. They are completely unrelated.  Vin– can be grounded because it's an **input**. And the amplifier takes the difference of the inputs, and generates **differential** output. We don't know the output configuration, but it's differential so I assume that there are two op amps for each output phase. So, shorting the output of an op amp to ground may cause some trouble. But again, it's an assumption, and datasheet doesn't state anything related. Of course you can use one input but what if the diff outputs don't have exactly equal amplitude?